# What are the similar characteristics of Swami Nammalwar and Jadabaratha?

Tags: scripture, alwar

There are some similar characteristics found in [Swami Nammalwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nammalvar) and Jadabaratha. Can the answer be given in detail by mentioning the characteristics?

Comment: Is jadabharata = Bharata the Chandravanshi Kshatriya son of Shakuntala?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_(emperor) Acharya Nammalwar was a great devotee of Parabramhan Shriman Narayana while he too was a pandya prince he was thrown away by his parents due to his physical handicap and he refused to talk to anyone. I don't see any similarities between them

Comment: @Yogi Both are mahanubhavas   Jadabaratha once lifted the palanquin of a king who wanted to get educated and was search of a mahanubhava. Jadabaratha ( till that moment has not spoke to anybody and wore torn clothes)  unruly  carried the palanquin and the king got hurt in the melee. He got down and asked jadabaratha why he did. Like a flood of nectar the advises came from Jadabaratha and the king was in search of this mahanubava only. Swami Namalwar was not thrown away by his parents.Read Namalwar vaibhavam. He spoke after 16 years from birth and resided in tamarind tree hole without any food.